# Stop previously played WAV sound

Tags: java, netbeans, wav

I am making a desktop Softphone-like application in Java. I want to add the dialed-number sounds (DTMF). For example, when I dial 51, it plays `dtmf5.wav` after pressing the 5, but then it plays `dtmf1.wav` when I press the 1, without stopping the 5's tone. How do I make sure only one sound - the latest one - plays at once?

This is what I'm using to play the sound:

```
private void lbl01MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)         {                                    
    String val=txtdisplay.getText() + "1";
    txtdisplay.setText(val);
    if (evt.getSource() == lbl01)  {
        URL urlClick = StartGUI.class.getResource("/Dtmf/dtmf1.wav");
        AudioClip click = Applet.newAudioClip(urlClick);
        click.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop any previously playing audio, you can keep a reference to the `AudioClip` when it is created. When the action is sent to play a Clip just stop the previous clip by calling it's `stop` method.

```
AudioClip currentAudio = null;

...

private void lbl01MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                    
    String val=txtdisplay.getText() +"1";
    txtdisplay.setText(val);
    if ( currentAudio != null ){
        currentAudio.stop();
    }
    if (evt.getSource() == lbl01) 
    {

        URL urlClick = StartGUI.class.getResource("/Dtmf/dtmf1.wav");
        currentAudio = Applet.newAudioClip(urlClick);
        currentAudio.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: its working but now I have to add some delay.. Thanks for help.. :-)